# How to bind an onclick event fired in a JavaScript library to an Angular function?

Tags: javascript, angular, dhtmlx

How can I bind an "onclick" event triggered from an external visual library (DHTMLX Gantt) inside an Angular component with a function of that same Angular component?

Environment:

- Angular 6 App
- External Visual JavaScript Library (DHTMLX Gantt)

Component.html

```
<div #gantt_here style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
```

Component.ts

```
export class ProjectManagementGanttComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('gantt_here') ganttContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Config Gantt Library
    gantt.config.columns = [
      {name: 'tree', width: 30,
        template: '<input type=button onclick=expand_task(' + task.id + ') value=+>'
      },
      {name: 'text',       label: 'Task name',  width: '*'}
    ];

    // Init Gantt Library
    gantt.init(this.ganttContainer.nativeElement);
  }
```

Comment: Have you try this: gantt.attachEvent("onLinkClick", () => { /*your code here*/ });

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, its not a default event of the library, but a generic javascript onclick event that must be treated inside of the angular component

Comment: You wrote: I bind an "onclick" event triggered from an external visual library. So maybe you mean that DOM element created by this library will fire the onclick event.

Comment: Yes, that's it: the library accepts a given column definition. One of the columns has a custom template: '<input type=button onclick=expand_task(' + task.id + ') value=+>'. The code that the onclick triggers must be inside Angular and not a regular Javascript function. That's my problem.